# mvc controller read signalr value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

We are currently using asp.net MVC with SignalR to communicate with the browser's client side code.

Currently our hub is built as:

```
public class SectionHub : Hub
{
}
```

MVC controller gets a reference to it.  And within a loop it uses the hub to notify the client when certain steps are done:

```
var progressHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SectionHub>();
progressHub.Clients.All.updateCurrentProgress(....)
```

All this works fine.  We are now adding a stop button on the client and want to notify the MVC controller to stop the process when it's clicked.  We updated the SectionHub to include a property which the client is able to update.  However, since the progressHub object is an **IHubContext** it does not have access to that property.  Is there anyway to get the new property into the hub and have it accessible in the MVC controller, or create the hub as a SectionHub rather than IHubContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have that kind of logic in the hub, the hub should only be used to push state. Move all code to a background worker, let the MVC controller action queue the work and return directly (Long running controller action is a anti pattern). let the stop MVC controller action call the worker queue and tell it to stop the work.

Thats a much more solid solution if you ask me.

edit: Btw, I think my library would help you, you could use it to seamless push progress state from your worker to your clients
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Even if you would find a way to get an *handle* on a `SectionHub` instance, it would not work properly because those instances are created *and dropped* at each request, therefore its value would not be reliable.

My advice is, use whatever way you think fits the best to access that property in a *global* way: a static variable, a dependency-injected service, a database record, a queuing system. Those are all reliable ways to reach your goal (of course some more, some less, it depend on your requirements about fault tolerance, and on the degree of modularity you are trying to achieve).

PS: your code lets anybody stop notifications *for everybody* to be sent, is this really what you want? Just curious, it might have an impact on the question itself.